# Sequelize: findOne auto commits during transaction (using clsHooked)

Tags: node.js, transactions, sequelize.js

I have code similar to below:

```
const _addEvents = async(eventList, day, transaction) => {
  await eventList.forEach(event => {
    return model.events.findOne({where:event, transaction: transaction}).then(event => {
        if(!event) {
          transaction.rollback();
          throw new Error("event not found");
        }

        return event;
      })
      .then(event => {
        day.addEvents(event, {through: {status: 'ENABLED'}});
        day.save();
      })
    })
  }
}

export const create = async(attributes) => {
        return await sequelize.transaction(async(t) => {
            return model.days.create(attributes, {transaction: t})).then(async(day) => {
                await _addEvents(attributes.eventList, day, t);
                return day;
            })
        })
}
```

What I'm seeing is the transaction begins and a row is added to days within the transaction. In the first iteration when `findOne` is called within the method `_addEvents` the transaction is committed.

I have used `Sequelize.useCLS("foo");` so I expect all transactions to be in the same namespace *however* I'm passing the transaction just to be sure.

Can anyone tell me why the transaction is committing after `findOne` is executed and in doing so tell me how to avoid this happening.

I'm using (babel-core 6.26.3) and node.js v9.2.0 & postgres 10.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [@Jan Aagaard Meier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/800016/jan-aagaard-meier) & Co for revealing the issue.

My problem was the `await eventList.forEach` was not doing what I *hoped* it would do.

`Array.prototype.forEach` will return `undefined`. It will return irrelevant of the state of the promises within the loop.

Therefore the COMMIT occurs because the transaction function is completed before the lost Promises (within the loop) can complete.

A solution is to use [bluebird's Promise.map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) which turns that line into

```
await Promise.map(eventList, async(event) => {
    await model.events.findOne({where:event, transaction: transaction}).then(event => {
    ....
    }
});
```

Here the map will wait until all the sub Promises complete and as we return a Promise (and await on it) we ensure we do not complete the transaction before map completes.

Answer (score 1):

`_addEvents` is doing asynchronous work, but `sequelize.transaction` does not know that it needs to wait for it finish. CLS takes care of passing the transaction into nested contexts, but you still need to make sure you are waiting for all queries to finish.

`await _addEvents(attributes.eventList, day, t);`

In `model.days.create` you need to pass the transaction as the second argument, see http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-create

In general I would recommend using *either* CLS, or passing the transaction everywhere you use it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm passing the transaction just for clarity but know CLS handles it if I don't. I've updated example as your comments on syntax are correct and I've added async / await as suggested. Issue still exists.